Nextjs does not respect serverComponentsExternalPackages in production
I try to bundle react code in a nextjs api using esbuild. It works on local fine but not in production.
Here is my serverComponentsExternalPackages configuration.
experimental: {
    serverComponentsExternalPackages: [
      "esbuild",
      "@tremor/react",
      "lucide-react",
    ]
  },

I print node_modules in api call on production (it is hosted on vercel).

it adds 'esbuild' in there but not 'lucide-react' or any other packages.
Binaries:
      Node: 21.1.0
      npm: 10.2.0
    Relevant packages:
      next: 14.1.1
      react: 18.2.0
      react-dom: 18.2.0
      typescript: 5.0.4

It there any solution/workaround for this issue?
I tried adding them by webpack config or transpilePackages but neither worked.
